# Editor doesnt show up as it should in SC

Tags: safecracker, editor

Because of the missing "usage" docs in DevDemons site, i dunno what i need to do to get the Editor shown in SC form.

I thought this would do the trick but it was a no-go:

```
<p>
                        <label ><h3>Body</h3>< /label ><br />
                        <textarea name="edtr_body" rows="10" cols="50" style="width:90%; background-color:#b3c1cd;"></textarea>
                    </p>
```

Someone for sure can tell how to add this fieldtype to SC?
Thanks.

PS: i am using html5 template.

Answer (score 1):

Well ok. It was as simple as to change the < textarea NAME -> ID. and it shows up. Thank you!